# Превратить список списков в плоский список однострочником (без использования дополнительных модулей)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

У меня есть список списков:

```
arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 4]]
```

Необходимо получить все элементы (числа) из данной конструкции.

Реализовал в лоб:

```
res = []
for obj in arr:
    res += [elem for elem in obj]
```

Но хочется однострочного решения.

Подскажите, можно ли его стандартными средствами (без дополнительных библиотек) реализовать?

Перебрал несколько вариантов, пока ничего не нашел.

---

PS: нашел такой "изврат", но это все таки богомерзкий "изврат", а не красивое решение:

```
res = list(map(int, ' '.join(f"{obj[0]} {obj[1]}" for obj in arr).split()))
```

Comment: `без дополнительных библиотек` - это без модулей вообще или без модулей, которые необходимо устанавливать дополнительно?

Comment: @MaxU, лучше конечно без модулей вообще

Comment: `[x for xs in arr for x in xs]` же

Comment: @extrn, пробовал этот вариант, но в неправильном порядке :) поэтому ошибки сыпались, да, решение очень хорошее, просто не сталкивался именно с таким способом `for` организовывать

Comment: @Zhihar порядок как в обычном вложенном цикле, только результат в начале а не в конце. то же касается и if. `[x for ... if ... for ... if .. for ...]` тоже допустимо

Comment: надо будет поиграться, чтобы усвоить

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [параметром sum(..., start=[])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
res = sum(arr, [])
```

результат:

```
In [4]: res
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4]
```

---

Но наиболее идиоматичным решением в данном случае будет использование [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). Об этом даже есть упоминание в [`docstring` по встроенной функции `sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

> To concatenate a series of iterables, consider using
> itertools.chain().

```
from itertools import chain

res = list(chain.from_iterable(arr))
```

---

**UPDATE:** сравнение скорости выполнения разных решений:

```
In [9]: %timeit sum([list(range(1000))]*1000, [])
2.25 s ± 69.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [10]: %timeit [x for xs in [list(range(1000))]*1000 for x in xs]
27.9 ms ± 428 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit list(chain.from_iterable([list(range(1000))]*1000))
11.8 ms ± 266 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: блин, ведь пробовал сумму, но про начальное значение напрочь забыл, а оно по умолчанию - `0`, что приводило к ошибке, кстати - если там в списке кортежи, то из-за их константности придется первоначально превратить кортежи в списки

Comment: @Zhihar, в "продакшн" коде я бы всё-таки использовал `itertools.chain` вместо хака с `sum()`...

Comment: А вот чего там не сказано, так это то, что sum отработает за O(n^2) :)

Comment: кстати на счет списка кортежей я погорячился - достаточно сделать sum(arr, ()), правда на выходе тоже кортеж, но это не важно

Comment: @extrn, а откуда там O(n^2), по идее же там последовательный анализ по 1 элементу

Comment: @extrn, я вот тоже не уверен что там `O(n^2)` ...

Comment: `result = []; result = result + [1, 2]; result = result + [3, 4]` и т.д. Обратите внимание, не +=, а именно так. Можете сравнить `sum([list(range(1000))]*1000, [])` и `[x for xs in [list(range(1000))]*1000 for x in xs]` по скорости

Comment: @extrn, мда... разница в скорости - 81 раз

Comment: @MaxU так будет даже хуже `sum([list(range(10))]*100000, [])` Квадратичная сложность в чистом виде.

Comment: @extrn, это понятно)